# Why doesn't calendar of DateTimePicker pop up?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using datetimepicker and whenever I put the HTML above the datatable HTML the calendar shows up. But when I put it as a header through which I could filter the datatable with it. The calendar doesn't show up and probably hides behind the datatable. What can be done to fix this problem?

```js
   $.filterTable($orderTable, '#filterButton');
    $.filterTable($orderTable, 'button.filterButton');

    $('#devicetimestamp').daterangepicker({
        singleDatePicker: true,
        locale: {
            format: 'DD-MM-YYYY',
            daysOfWeek: weekdays,
            monthNames: months,
            applyLabel: $labelOk,
            cancelLabel: $labelCancel
        },
        showISOWeekNumbers: true,
        showDropdowns: true,
        minDate: "01/01/2015",
        autoUpdateInput: false,
        autoApply: true
    });
    $('#devicetimestamp').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev,picker) {
        $(this).val(picker.startDate.format('DD-MM-YYYY'));
        clickFilterButton();
    });
    $('input.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
        format: 'DD-MM-YYYY',
        locale: $lang,
        showClose: true,
        widgetPositioning: {
            horizontal: 'left',
            vertical: 'auto'
        },
        toolbarPlacement: 'top',
        showClear: true
    });
```

```html
 <div class="panel-body">
                        <table id="orderTable" class="table table-striped table-condensed table-hover">
                            <thead>
                            <tr class="filter">
                                <th><button type="submit" id="filterButton" class="btn btn-warning filterButton">
                                    <g:message code="general.filter.button" default="Filter"/>
                                </th>
                                <th><input class="form-control" size="10"
                                           placeholder="${message(code: 'order.filter.employeeid', default: 'Filter Employee')}"
                                           data-column-index="1"/>
                                </th>
                                <th> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="devicetimestamp" name="displaydate_filter" data-column-index="2"
                                            placeholder="${message(code: 'communication.filter.displayDate.placeholder', default: 'DD-MM-YYYY')}"
                                            title="${message(code: 'communication.filter.displaydate.info', default: 'Date after')}" maxlength="10" size="10"/>
                                </th>
                                <th><input class="form-control" size="10"
                                           placeholder="${message(code: 'order.filter.servertimestamp', default: 'Filter Servertimestamp')}"
                                           data-column-index="3"/>
                                </th>
                                <th><input class="form-control" size="10"
                                           placeholder="${message(code: 'order.filter.device', default: 'Filter Device')}"
                                           data-column-index="4"/>
                                </th>
                                <th><input class="form-control" size="10"
                                           placeholder="${message(code: 'order.filter.locationid', default: 'Filter Location')}"
                                           data-column-index="5"/>
                                </th>
                                <th><input class="form-control" size="10"
                                           placeholder="${message(code: 'order.filter.productid', default: 'Filter Product')}"
                                           data-column-index="6"/>
                                </th>
                                <th><input class="form-control" size="10"
                                           placeholder="${message(code: 'order.filter.quantity', default: 'Filter Quantity')}"
                                           data-column-index="7"/>
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="header">
                                <th><g:message code="order.employeeid.label" default="employee_id"/></th>
                                <th><g:message code="order.devicetimestamp.label" default="devicetimestamp"/></th>
                                <th><g:message code="order.servertimestamp.label" default="servertimestamp"/></th>
                                <th><g:message code="order.device.label" default="device"/></th>
                                <th><g:message code="order.locationid.label" default="location_id"/></th>
                                <th><g:message code="order.productid.label" default="product_id"/></th>
                                <th><g:message code="order.quantity.label" default="quantity"/></th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                        </table>
                    </div>
```

EDIT:

I tried changes and now the calendar pops up but the months show up  as undefined. Anyone an idea how this can be fixed?

[how it looks now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MvDDz.png)

Comment: most likely by setting z-index on the bottom-menu, but it's only a guess

Comment: I added z-index 99 to the style and it didnt change it sadly

Comment: set `z-index` to higher value say 99999999999999. Your snippet have some bugs too.

Comment: I tried style="z-index: 999999999999999" it didnt do anything sadly

Comment: @Darknax Please try to include a working code . The above snippet is not working